# How build notification with custom layout from jar-library

Tags: java, android, jar, notifications, remoteview

I create jar library under android. I need create own custom notification with my layout's style and custom action's when user click on views inside layout. And I must use notification from any application with my jar library.

From developer docs i can create custom notification only by RemoteViews:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationInfo().packageName, id_of_my_layout);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setContent(remoteViews);
```

But inside jar file i can't create any xml-resources and layouts, and i can't use 'id_of_my_layout' because i not have any resources.

There any way for create custom notifications inside jar library?

Comment: Why not use an Android library project, packaged as an AAR? Then, you can have resources.

Comment: @CommonsWare AAR can used as JAR inside old projects? for example, AAR will work from app with <=2.3 targetSdk?

Comment: "AAR can used as JAR inside old projects?" -- I do not know what you mean by this. "AAR will work from app with <=2.3 targetSdk?" -- yes. AARs in general are not tied to any particular `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion`, or `targetSdkVersion`. They are merely a way of packaging code, resources, assets, and manifest entries.